How can I get jacoco coverage on methods called by reflection?
I'm using jacoco version 0.8.12.
I'm using a vendor library which calls the code that I want to test.
The vendor library instantiates the class from a package I have registered in the application as a client package by performing a Class.forName(myClientPackage + "path.to.Handler") and calling the method handle(...) from my implementation of vendor interface Handler.
I'd like to know how to gain coverage from such methods called by reflection.
It works well inside Eclipse. The code called by reflection is highlighted in green.
I might be missing a special option from jacoco that is disabled by default.
I use gradle to generate the jacoco report:
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
  toolVersion = '0.8.12'
}

task javaCodeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: test) {
  sourceDirectories = files(['src/main/java'])
  classDirectories = files(['build/classes/main'])
  executionData = files('build/jacoco/test.exec')
  reports {
    xml.enabled = true
    html.enabled = true
  }
}


Without Complete Minimal Reproducible Example hard to reproduce your issue, but let's try using java.util.function.Consumer as what you name "vendor interface", then what you name "implementation of vendor interface" can be
src/main/java/Example.java
import java.util.function.Consumer;

class Example implements Consumer<String> {
    public void accept(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

and call via reflection from a test
src/test/java/ExampleTest.java
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Consumer c = (Consumer) Class.forName("Example").newInstance();
        c.accept("Hello");
    }
}

with following
build.gradle
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("jacoco")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")
}

execution of gradle test jacocoTestReport produces the following report as expected

